# Use Heun's method without iteration to solve a second order differential equation, Chapra Numerical methods 7th edition chapter 25 p.3

Tags: numerical-methods

I've spent a day trying to solve this problem and I can't figure out how:

Use the (b) Heun (without iteration) method to
solve
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2}-0.5t+y=0$$
where $y(0)=2$ and $y'(0)=0$. Solve from x=0 to 4 using h=0.1.

Someone who really knows how to think please just show the first two or three steps. If you don't see the circular dilemma, or think I'm referring to the order of the error please don't respond. The answer I've posted below. You are starting from the second derivative and have to use $y''$ slope to find $y'$ which you then use to find $y^j_{i+1}$ which would have been used to plug into $y'$ to average the slopes to find $y_{i+1}$ but we started from $y''$. For a reminder a link to heun's rule I linked below too. I assume anyone who can answer this and get the right numbers wouldn't need a reminder for the easy first derivative version. Thankfully there's NO iteration. Just average the slopes once.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TrO0YEHpxxWDFaRkJoZWFyclk/view?usp=sharing

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun%27s_method

Comment: By iteration in this book, Chapra means in a first order version don't take $y_{i+1}$'s slope and average it with y_{i}'s slope to find a new $y^j_{i+1}$ until the $y^j$ and $y^{j+1}$ differ by a certain percent.  In the second order version I have not idea because I don't know if the step from $y''$ to $y'$ is also averaged  or even how to do that because you need the $y^{j+1}$ value to plug back into the $y''$ which would require you to step through $y'$ so in essence I'm totally confused with my pseudo mathematical explanation.

Comment: Please move you additional remark to the body of the question. That is, among others, what the edit function is for. -- Is the google drive text your own work or a copy of the provided (partial) solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To break the circle, you do exactly as indicated in the partial solution, you transform into a system of order 1. Set $z=y'$, then
$$
\frac d{dt}\binom yz =\binom{z}{0.5·t-y}
$$
This now has the required form $u'=f(t,u)$ and can be used in a generic Heun solver

```
import numpy as np

def ODEfunc(t,u):
    y,z = u
    return np.array([ z, 0.5*t-y ])



def HeunStep(f,t,u,h):
    k1 = h*f(t, u)
    k2 = h*f(t+h, u+k1)
    return u+0.5*(k1+k2)

def HeunTest(f,a,b,x0,h):
    t = a
    x = x0.copy()
    while t < b+0.5*h:
        print t, x
        x = HeunStep(f,t,x,h)
        t=t+h


HeunTest(ODEfunc,0,4,np.array([2.,0.]),0.1)
```

---

Also note that you can easily obtain the exact solution 
$$
y(t)=2\cos(t)-0.5\sin(t)+0.5t
$$
by standard methods to compare against.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try working the problem again tonight. I can't remember which value I got stuck on but there was a z on the first step that I didn't know how to get. If you've compiled this before maybe I'll see what value of Z python is using.

Comment: That was it! I finally had free time to look back at this problem and you just have to calculate using heun's method on both z' and and y' simultaneously. I don't know why I found this so confusing. The 4th order Runge-Kutta method over a second derivative does this times four and I just did that intuitively when the formula was in front of me.